# Is a JSON array absolutely necessary for a list of JSON objects stored as carriage-delimited lines?

Tags: java, json

Suppose I have an extremely large data set, where each data item is serialized as a JSON object. When I place these into a file, I have two choices.

(1) I can write them out as one JSON object per line, delimited by carriage returns / newlines:

```
{ jsonobject }
{ jsonobject }
...
```

(2) However, the official spec says the above formatting isn't legal. I have to use a JSON array:

```
[
  { jsonobject },
  { jsonobject }
]
```

I think the first approach is easier to parse in code because you can read in one text line at a time (I'm using Java and will use BufferedReader.readLine()), and then parse that line into a JSON object.

The second approach may run out of memory depending on what parser you're using, right? The parser may need to read the whole file into memory to construct the array.

What is the best practice for this problem?

Comment: Link to official spec? What is this in context to?

Comment: And what happens when you have a JSON object that contains a newline embedded in a string?

Comment: @JAB: I have escaped out all newlines.

Comment: You shouldn't be using JSON for data sets that are too large to parse. Use a managed data base. If it will fit in memory use option 2 and a proper JSON parser.

Comment: Parsers don't need to suck in the whole file - Jackson - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson - supports streaming JSON.  Requires work, but it's pretty fast.

Comment: @NG: I don't know what parser the downstream customer will be using.